# How to covert INT to VARCHAR in SQL condition

Tags: mysql, sql, int, varchar

select...
from...
where R.WORK_YM = 201611

how to change R.WORK_YM to String value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select... from... where cast(R.WORK_YM as varchar(10))= '201611'
```

Comment: It's not work for my sql and here is the error:

[Error Code: -461, SQL State: 42846]  DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -461, SQLSTATE: 42846, SQLERRMC: SYSIBM.INTEGER;SYSIBM.VARCHAR
..

Comment: Its for mssql . Try this for mysql :

select... from... where cast(R.WORK_YM as char(10))= '201611'

Comment: my job is doing on mssql Beauty!

Comment: Did the next query work?

Comment: YES! IT WORKS, THANK YOU xD

Comment: Can you please submit my comment as answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this Query for SQL Server,

Use `CONVERT` function

```
select * from Table R where CONVERT(varchar(10), R.WORK_YM) = '201611'
```

OR

Use `STR` function

```
select * from Table R where STR(R.WORK_YM,10) = '201611'
```

OR

Use `CAST` function

```
select * from Table R where CAST(R.WORK_YM as varchar(10)) = '201611'
```

For MySQL,

Use `CAST` function

```
select * from Table R where CAST(R.WORK_YM as Char(10)) = '201611'
```

Use `CONVERT` function

```
select * from Table R where CONVERT(Char(10), R.WORK_YM) = '201611'
```

Comment: I tried every  query you posted but it's still not work and the error is:
Error Code: -461, SQL State: 42846]  DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -461, SQLSTATE: 42846, SQLERRMC: SYSIBM.INTEGER;SYSIBM.VARCHAR

Comment: no worries , I got the answer from Ranjana Ghimire:

where cast(R.WORK_YM as char(10))= '201611'

Thank you!

Comment: ohh you are using mysql. ok great

Answer (score 0):

for conversion in oracle use

> `to_char(201611)`

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm